# Create Event with Microsoft Graph REST API: Can we customise or disable event invitation email?

Tags: outlook, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating event using v1.0/users/test@domain.com/events and this API is sending out the email to all attendees.

1. I want to disable this email from REST API.
2. If disabling is not possible then I want to customise that email template with signature section where Microsoft Teams Meeting section is there. Also want to remove Meeting ID and Passcode As per the attached screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use the graph event api to set custum body of text meeting

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
{
  "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does mid month work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2019-03-15T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a meeting with attendees, there is NO way to disable the invite to be send. This is just how it works.

If you create the event and set isOnlineMeeting to true, the text you want to remove is added automatically. Also not possible to remove (in one call).

I have this alternative for you.
You create the event with the api without attendees and with isOnlineMeeting set to true.

You then patch the event where you change the body of the event and add the attendees.